# What is Naruto's second element?

Tags: naruto

After a long time of hard work, most ninja get a second Nature element. While Naruto's first one is wind, I don't recall his second one being mentioned.

What was Naruto's second nature ability?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Naruto's natural affinity is **Wind Release**, which he learned from *Asuma Sarutobi* to flow into his weapons to increase their offensive might.

Via *Six Paths Sage Mode*, Naruto can utilize all **Five Nature Transformations**, as well as **Yin–Yang Release**. He can make perfect use of the latter to revitalise life-forces, heal whomever he touches, and even restore missing organs. This ability, however, has its limits as he was unable to fully restore *Might Guy's* leg after his use of *Night Guy*, or save *Obito Uchiha* from *Kaguya's* *All-Killing Ash Bones*.

With chakra from the *Tailed Beasts*, Naruto can also use *Kekkei Genkai* such as the **Magnet Release**, **Lava Release**, and **Boil Release** from *Shukaku*, *Son Gokū*, and *Kokuō*, respectively.

**TOP-LEFT**: **[Sage Art: Magnet Release Rasengan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Art:_Magnet_Release_Rasengan)**
**LOWER-LEFT**: **[Sage Art: Lava Release Rasenshuriken](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Art:_Lava_Release_Rasenshuriken)**
**RIGHT**: **[Boil Release: Unrivalled Strength](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boil_Release:_Unrivalled_Strength)** (*Naruto uses in Manga only as of 4/11/2016*)

[image]

Comment: pffft , , , i just realized Rasengan looks like Devil Fruit :v

Comment: no Spoiler alert :/

Comment: Currently, this answer is still spoiler?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that Rasengan is a wind technic. To learn Rasenshuriken, Naruto has to focus on life energy.

So I believe there are two basic elements; one which Sasuke hiers the eyes which includes lightning and fire techniques, and Naruto's which is the body. He has more control over his physical strength, but if Naruto's second ability would be anything, it would be the life energy.

Comment: Rasengan is actually a dense mass of chakra without any chakra element attached to it.  Naruto learned Rasenshruiken by combining his wind chakra with the dense, swirling mass of chakra in the Rasengan technique.  Naruto's Sage mode allows him to make use of the Rasenshruiken by throwing it instead of by normal contact with an enemy, since he'd suffer the effects of the technique if he used it like he would a normal Rasengan.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the Kurama is inside of Naruto, and Kurama's chakra natures are Wind and Fire, so I guess it would be fire.

Comment: This doesn't mean that Naruto has an inherited Fire chakra nature. If Kurama is Fire/Wind (which believe isn't fully cannon), then Naruto can merely tap into the Fire nature of Kurma; similar to how he taps into Shukaku's Magnet Release

Answer (score -3):

Every ninja has at least two elements; Kekkei Genkai and Tota excluded as those have elements that combine to make a release form.

Naruto's second element while training with Yamato and Kakashi before learning sage mode, my guess would be water. Water beats Fire, wind beats lightning which is why in their clash on the rooftop the Rasengan did more damage than the Chidori, putting aside the fact the Chidori was meant to be a one-hit kill as lightning enhances your speed and striking power while wind enables you to cut better as with Asuma's knives cloaked in wind chakra.

Comment: There is no evidence to suggest anywhere that Naruto learned a second element before the battle with Madara.

Comment: Its completely false that "every ninja has at least two elements". The only basis to say that is the fact that Most Jonin have by the time they become Jonin have learned how to use more than 1 nature as said by Kakashi. Your natural element does not prevent you from using any other elements, but usually if you have more than one natural element, you also have a Kekkei Genkai, which are not released forms, but just combined elements. Also, The Rasengan is a non elemental Jutsu, it did more damage than the Chidori because its an explosive torrent of chakra, instead of a piercing stab.